# MqttException (0) - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed using MQTTAndroid Client

Tags: android, ssl, mosquitto

This is the error I am getting in my android client for accessing mosquitto mqtt broker running on my raspberrypi

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x90e76d40: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer

This is the part of the code that is trying to connect

> keystore.bks contains my CA.crt and client.crt

```
client = new MqttAndroidClient(getApplicationContext(), "ssl://192.168.43.112:1883", clientId);
InputStream input = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("keystore.bks");
options = new MqttConnectOptions();
options.setSocketFactory(client.getSSLSocketFactory(input,"password"));
IMqttToken token = client.connect(options);
token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
         Log.d("Connection", "Connected to Broker ");
         //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ConnectiontoMQTTBrokerMade", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         pubConnect.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         pubDisconnect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         pubPub.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         ipinputpublish.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         messagemqtt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ConnectiontoMQTTBrokerRejected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exception.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("Connection Error", exception.toString());
        Log.d("Connection", "Unable to connect to Broker");
    }
});
```

On the **broker side** ,I am getting this log

> New connection from 192.168.43.1 on port 1883.
>
> Socket error on client , disconnecting.

mosquitto.conf -

```
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid 
persistence true 
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/ 
include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d 

cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.crt 
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt 
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key 
require_certificate true
```

if I use

```
mosquitto_sub -t 'test/topic' -v --cafile ca.crt --cert client.crt --key client.key
```

It get's subscribed.

Can someone tell me what is causing this error ?

Comment: You might want to edit the question to include your mosquitto.conf file so we can see how you've set up SSL in the broker

Comment: I have added the mosquitto.conf file above